# Exception while doing arc land

Tags: git, phabricator

I have moved from tortoise svn recently and am new to git and phabricator, so pardon me if I am asking some very basic question.

What I have read from the documentation I should follow these steps for pushing my local changes to remote origin master.

1. create a branch for working.
2. do your work then do 'arc diff' and get it reviewed from peer
3. do 'arc land'

In the last step I get following exception

```
Usage Exception: Local branch 'master' is ahead of remote branch 'origin/master', so landing a feature branch would push additional changes. Push or reset the changes in 'master' before running 'arc land'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It means you have made some changes on local master branch which have not been pushed to remote. And your feature branch originated from a commit on your local master that has not yet been pushed to remote.

If I understand it right, your logs must be something like:

```
            E----F----G
           /          ^
A----B----C----D      |
     ^         ^   FEATURE
     |         |
org/master   master
```

Now you are trying to push FEATURE. Hence its giving that error. Try pushing master first and then Feature.

(I am assuming arc land pushes your current branch)

Comment: Did it solve the problem? If so then accept the solution, so that others can use it!

/Cheers